# Why define the 'x' int (C)

Tags: c

I have a problem. When I declare the 'x' integer the program works properly but when I delete that 'x' it shows me a strange result.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    main ()
    {
        int a,b,x;
        char ras;
        printf("Insert a: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Insert b: ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        printf("Sum or multuply: (s/m)");
        scanf("%s", &ras);
        if (ras=='s')
        {
            printf("Sum is :%d", a+b);
        }
        else if (ras=='m')
        {
            printf("Multiply is :%d", a*b);
        }
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: take off the trailing `**` in the declaration `int **x**`.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &ras);` should be `scanf("%c", &ras);`

Comment: @Leonardo I think he’s using `**` for emphasis. It’s not in his actual code. :)

Comment: A variable name should be without `'` e.g. `int x;` is correct but `int  'x';`  is  wrong

Comment: Sorry about 'x' and ** it was the bold thing from menu. I wrote x

Answer (score 2):

Your program invokes undefined behaviour either way because `scanf` stores two characters (the entered letter plus the trailing 0-byte), but the pointer you gave it points to a variable that can contain only a single character.

In your particular implementation it so happens, that the 0-byte will simply override the x variable if that variable exists. If it doesn't you overrides something else, leading to your strange result.

To read a single character, you should use `%c`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put "%s" in scanf pattern, it is for a string - at least two characters (what you want plus NULL). Use %c instead.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code invokes undefined behavior, and apparently, it's doing this "funny" thing.

The reason for the UB is that the `%s` conversion specifier makes `scanf()` append a terminating NUL character beyond the character just scanned, but there's no room for it, so it writes to unallocated memory...

---

Use `%c` instead. **Better yet, get rid of `scanf()` completely,** it's evil. Use a sane function, such as `getchar()`, instead.